# Java jFrame. ProgressBar с потоками

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar

Есть `класс`, который создает потоки (в которых выполняется некий код). 
Форму создавал при помощи `jFrame`, добавил туда `ProgressBar`:

```
progressBar = new JProgressBar();
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
progressBar.setMinimum(0);
progressBar.setMaximum(100);
```

Программа выполняется долгое количество времени, поэтому хотелось бы для пользователя показать, что она еще выполняется.

Каким способом можно сделать так, что бы ползунок `progressbar` бегал **туда-сюда** до конца выполнения всех потоков? А если можно сделать по процентам, что бы еще показывало, было бы еще лучше!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Java Swing для выполнения продолжительных операций и оповещения `EventDispathThread` о промежуточных результатах предназначен `SwingWorker`, если быть совсем точным, в Вашем случае `SwingWorker<Void, Integer>`, в котором Вы должны для этого реализовать 2 метода:

```
@Override
public Void doInBackground() {
    ...
    publish(1);
    ...
    publish(100);
    return null;
}
```

собственно код продолжительной операции,  в котором вы должны сами передавать промежуточные результаты при помощи вызова `publish`, и

```
@Override
protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
    progressBar.setValue(chunks.get(chunks.size()-1));
}
```

в котором вы обрабатываете результат из другого потока уже в EDT.

В случае с несколькими параллельными потоками вычислять процент выполнения несколько сложнее, но принцип останется тот же.

Comment: А после реализации этих двух методов, как и что надо вызывать в форме ?

Comment: ну я же там написал:  progressBar.setValue(chunks.get(chunks.size()-1));

Comment: извиняюсь, затупил !) Спасибо большое ! Буду пробовать